# Can a wire transfer be reversed?

Tags: wire-transfer

It has been 18 days since my dad did a wire transfer from India to Canada and I still haven't got my money. When my dad contacted his bank they are saying the money has been received but my bank is saying that I have received no money. All the information that was filled in like swift code and account number were correct. Is there anything that can be done in this situation.

Comment: " When my dad contacted his bank they are saying the money has been received" Are they saying it was received by the information you sent? Or just that it was sent? Have you asked your bank to confirm that your payment details match your expectations? Have you asked his bank to confirm that the payment details for the transfer match your expectation?

Comment: What does either bank suggest that you do? Or have they run out of ideas?

Comment: They said it was received and my payment details are exactly the same.

Comment: Do you have any correspondence in writing from his bank, stating that payment was made and processed with exactly those details? I would suggest showing that to your bank and asking them what happened.

Comment: They have run out of ideas and from the looks of it they want me to do something but my bank is saying I'm not authorized to even access or even check that if a wire transfer with that transaction number was made or not.

Comment: Actually I so have the letter and confirmation receipt and can you suggest who should I contact here?

Comment: I mean should I contact a financial advisor or some other person from the bank?

Comment: "my bank is saying I'm not authorized to even access or even check that if a wire transfer with that transaction number was made or not." Are you sure you're the registered owner of the receiving account? Have you asked them to look at whether any amount was attempted to be wired to your account on that transaction date? If they continue to be unhelpful you may want to consider hiring a lawyer.

Comment: "I mean should I contact a financial advisor or some other person from the bank?" If it were me, I would be talking to every person from my bank I could possibly reach - tellers, phone line, financial advisers, managers, anyone and everyone.

Comment: I have an appointment with the manager and a financial advisor tommorow lets see what happens.

Comment: 1 - you definitely should not have waited 18 days. That's bad, very bad.  2 - it's important to understand about ***correspondent banks*** in wire transfers.  (Just google.)  The ***first thing you need to do*** is find out where the money went from bank A to bank B .. some correspondent bank .. before coming to your bank C.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I just have to attach a letter from my bank saying they never received any wire on that account number and my bank statement of one month to prove I never received anything and my dad's bank will be able to refund that.

Comment: @Shox Great, glad you got it resolved. You should write out your steps as a new answer, so that future visitors who google this with similar questions will know more clearly what worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to my financial advisor and showed her my papers for that wire transfer with all the sender's and receiver's details and because the receiver's bank info and his account number and mine matched she was able to give me a written letter that no wire transfer was made into that account and gave me the transaction history and my bank statement for these two months. After this I sent these three documents to the sender( In this case my dad) and his bank was able to cancel the wire.

There are two more things that my advisor told me. 1 If any of the receiver's bank info was wrong and any account with that wrong info doesn't exist that wire would have been cancelled and sent back to the sender or the third party company's account (if you did a wire through a third party) and the sender will have to request it back.

2. In any case the wire with wrong info was successful and received the bank would not be able to do anything. In this case the sender or his bank will have to contact the receiver and without the receiver's consent the wire can't be cancelled or reversed. You should contact your lawyer in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Ask your dad to lodge a Beneficiary claims non-receipt with his Bank. They can trace and inform if and when the payment was credited.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Contact the Indian Bank as soon as possible and alert them about possible error. They can request receiving bank about the deposit information and verify the transaction details.

Comment: But note that the ***person sending*** will have to do that.  The person supposedly receiving, is nobody.  (Anyone could randomly call a bank and assert they are supposed to be receiving money.)  The ***person sending*** must quickly act.